# Save a randomly generated value as both the key and value of a dict comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

Within a `dict` comprehension, how can I use a randomly generated value as both the key and value?

In my example use case I want to generate some random numbers and use these as the input to a function. I would like to save the the random numbers as they key and the function output given these numbers as the value.

Something like the following, however this implementation would generate different arrays of random numbers for the key and value.

```py
{
    tuple(sorted(rng.choice(1000, size=10, replace=False))): my_function(sorted(rng.choice(1000, size=10, replace=False)))
    for i in range(sample_size)
}
```

Reproducable example:

```py
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()

sample_size = 3


def my_function(x: np.array) -> int:
    return sum(x)


dictionary = {
    tuple(sorted(rng.choice(1000, size=3, replace=False))): my_function(sorted(rng.choice(1000, size=3, replace=False)))
    for i in range(sample_size)
}
```

An example output would be:

```
{(43, 70, 788): 2386, (56, 151, 613): 1074, (486, 645, 647): 2038}
```

The sum of the keys is not equal to the value because different random numbers were used. My desire is that the same random numbers are stored as the key and used in the function call. In this example it would mean that the sum of the keys was equal to the value.

Comment: Please provide more info on code and sample output.

Comment: What is `rng`? Please provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python3.8 or newer you can use [Assignment Expressions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/)

```
{tuple((arr := sorted(rng.choice(1000, size=10, replace=False)))): my_function(arr) for i in range(sample_size)}
```

Answer (score 1):

In python 3.8+, you can use the `:=` operator:

```
{(n:=tuple(sorted(rng.choice(1000, size=10, replace=False)))):my_function(n) for _ in range(sample_size)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just re-write your code  to use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression):

```
dictionary = {tuple(v): my_function(v) for v in (sorted(rng.choice(1000, size=3, replace=False)) for _ in range(sample_size))}
```

**Output** *(of a single run)*

```
{(92, 325, 573): 990, (361, 840, 913): 2114, (470, 669, 891): 2030}
```

As an alternative, is to use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
dictionary = {tuple(v): my_function(v) for v in
              map(lambda _: sorted(rng.choice(1000, size=3, replace=False)), range(sample_size))}

print(dictionary)
```

**Output** *(of a single run)*

```
{(45, 157, 889): 1091, (73, 353, 779): 1205, (275, 282, 633): 1190}
```

Both solutions will work in Python regardless of the version.